# 500 internal server error - Java webapp

Tags: java, mysql, maven, wildfly

I am relatively new to Java webapp development. I am using Maven, Wildfly and mySQL in developing the application.

I am stuck because when I enter data in the webapp it does not get saved to the database. I tried using Firebug to identify the error and the status code is '500 internal error'. I have my beans.xml in the WEB-INF and JAX-RS annotations, I can't seem to identify the problem. Please help.

my beans.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

My object class is:

```
package com.Malison.job.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;


import com.Malison.common.model.BaseEntity;


@Entity
@Table
public class Job extends BaseEntity {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@FormParam ("client")
@Column
private String client;

@FormParam ("location")
@Column (name = "Loaded_From")
private String loadedFrom;

@FormParam ("destination")
@Column
private String destination;

@Column
private int distance;

@FormParam ("product")
@Column
private String product;

@FormParam ("quantity")
@Column (name = "Quantity_Loaded")
private int quantityloaded;

@FormParam ("rate")
@Column (name = "Rate_of_Transport")
private int rateOfTransport;

@Column
private int amount = rateOfTransport * distance;

@FormParam ( "delivery")
@Column (name = "Delivery_Note_Number")
private int deliveryNoteNo;


@XmlElement (name = "distance")
public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(int distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public String getClient() {
    return client;
}


public void setClient(String client) {
    this.client = client;
}


public String getProduct() {
    return product;
}


public void setProduct(String product) {
    this.product = product;
}
public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}


public String getLoadedFrom() {
    return loadedFrom;
}

public void setLoadedFrom(String loadedFrom) {
    this.loadedFrom = loadedFrom;
}


public String getDestination() {
    return destination;
}

public void setDestination(String destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
}


public long getQuantityloaded() {
    return quantityloaded;
}

public void setQuantityloaded(int quantityloaded) {
    this.quantityloaded = quantityloaded;
}

public long getRateOfTransport() {
return rateOfTransport;
}

public void setRateOfTransport(int rateOfTransport) {
    this.rateOfTransport = rateOfTransport;
}


public long getDeliveryNoteNo() {
    return deliveryNoteNo;
}

public void setDeliveryNoteNo(int deliveryNoteNo) {
    this.deliveryNoteNo = deliveryNoteNo;
}




}
```

And my persistence class:

```
package com.Malison.job.restws;



import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;




import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.Form;




@Path("/job") // http://localhost:8085/malison/api/job
public class JobApi {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @POST
    @Path("/create") // http://localhost:8085/malison/api/job/create
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String create(@Form com.Malison.job.model.Job job){

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.merge(job);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            return "{\"success\":false, \"msg\":\"Error occured, please  try later\"}";
        }

        return "{\"success\":true, \"msg\": \"Saved successfully\"}";

    }


}
```

The following message is given on the Firebug log:

> Error processing request
>       Context Path:
>       /malison
>
> ```
> Servlet Path:
> /api
>
> Path Info:
> /job/create
>
> Query String:
> null
>
> Stack Trace
> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149)
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372)
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
> io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
> io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
> io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
> io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Comment: Please share your error message.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Firebug log?

Comment: I have looked at the firebug log and it shows the following message

Comment: I see an org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active exception. Try to search for this error and see if you get any information how to solve it.

Comment: @PeterMachariaNyota see my comment^

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of this

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active

The transaction has not been set up yet. Therefore, If you want to make the code run. You have two choices :

1. Using container managed transaction by changing the code to get the manager. or,

   ```
   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager em;
   ```
2. application managed transaction

   ```
   @PersistenceUnit
   private EntityManagerFactory emf;

   @Resource
   private UserTransaction utx;

   @POST
   @Path("/create") // http://localhost:8085/malison/api/job/create
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
   public String create(@Form com.Malison.job.model.Job job){

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em.merge(job);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            utx.rollback();
            return "{\"success\":false, \"msg\":\"Error occured, please  try later\"}";
        }
        return "{\"success\":true, \"msg\": \"Saved successfully\"}";
   }
   ```